# iphone app - white screen shows when launching, or when app suspends

Tags: ios, opengl-es, screen

we're having a bit of a headache with some apps, Perhaps anyone of you may be able to alleviate the pain, here goes:

We have an OpenGLES(1) application, and it works fine on any device yet tested, from ipod touch on 3.2 to iphone 4, ipad 1, with iOS 4.2.

however, when the user clicks 'home' twice while the app is running, the application view moves up to accommodate the phone's 'taskbar', but then the view turns white.

I suspect after reading various posts this is because I have not yet implemented the 'applicationWillResignActive' delegate method, but I'm unsure if this is indeed the case, and if so, how I would go about avoiding the white screen. Incidentally, there is also the problem that the background EAGLView goes white (or away ?) when an UIAlertView is added to the mainWindow.view, which seems to me a related problem.

I would much appreciate any suggestions.

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Your framebuffer is being destroyed, probably in EAGLView or somewhere similar.

Rebuild the framebuffer after you get control back.